# QLabel won't update pixmap from inside function

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qpixmap, qlabel, pixmap

I've tried absolutely everything I know, and I've come to the conclusion that this issue is over my head. I've tried running repaint(), update() and this->update(); and everything else that I could think of. Pixmap works outside of the function (in the constructor) but not inside a function. Here is code (only relevant is pasted, please indicate if you would like more):

myWidget.h

```
#define NUM_POINTERS 10


QLabel* pointerArray[NUM_POINTERS];
QPixmap circle;
QPixmap* triangle;
QPixmap* whitex;
int activePointer;
```

myWidget.cpp

```
activePointer = 0;

QPixmap circle (":/Resources/greencircle.png");
this->whitex = new QPixmap(":/Resources/white_x.png");
this->triangle = new QPixmap(":/Resources/redtriangle.png");

//create an array of pointers to the label1-10 objects
pointerArray[0] = ui->label1;
pointerArray[1] = ui->label2;
pointerArray[2] = ui->label3;
...
pointerArray[9] = ui->label10;

for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++)
{
    pointerArray[i]->setPixmap(circle);
}

void myWidget::changeImage()
{
  updatesEnabled();
  if (activePointer < 10){
      pointerArray[activePointer]->setPixmap(*this->whitex);
      activePointer++;
      update();
}
  else{
      printf("end of array\n");
      fflush(stdout);
  }

}
```

I get a row of circles printed where I want them, but I won't get any white Xs. The pixmap changes to the whitex, but it will not update. It does not crash, it continues adding to activePointer until the end of the array.

Thanks in advance.

Quick Edit: I have tried pointerArray[activePointer]->update(); with no luck.

Comment: I guess, you wrote a wrong path. That does not lead to a crash, only to an invalid QPixmap. your image names are greencircle and redtriangle, but white_x with underscore.

Comment: Check that `setPixmap(*this->whitex)` is executed for each `activePointer` that you want to. @x squared: no, if the pixmap was invalid, label would become blank instead of keeping circles.

Comment: Path is definitely correct, no spelling errors.

Comment: Have you tried declaring whitex on the stack, just like circle?

Comment: If I do that, I can't use it inside a function.